# Any up-to-date tutorial for the flexbox module?

Tags: css, flexbox

I know the [Flexible Box Layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) spec has changed, and some browsers now implement more than one version of it (using different syntaxes). I've been searching for information, but I can only find tutorials with warnings that they're now out of date.

I know the spec might change again, but I have an unusual use case (a Chrome extension) and I want to use it in its current form. I just want to know how to use the latest version implemented in Chrome.

Does anyone know of an up-to-date tutorial?

Comment: If you watch the mailing list or even the [ED](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/), you'll notice that it's going through an immense amount of change. I don't think you have anything more reliable than the changing spec itself at this point...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the best [flexbox tutorial](http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/) I have found so far, it is very well explained or if you need a deeper explanation check the [w3c draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

And for testing and better understanding of the flexbox model, check this [flexbox playground](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/).

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox modules aren't out of date just yet. The implementation of the new model is going to take time, probably a year to implement.

W3C always has the documentation for the standards and also notes of things that may not be implemented or not.

Here's the current [Flexbox Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

Here's the editor's draft of the new spec [Flexbox Layout Module 2012](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1):

Because the implementation has changed in the past there are know 2 major implementations of flexbox. [This page](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) provides some background information about the old and the new implementation.

I found a good tutorial for the current status of the implementation of Flexbox [here](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/).

Example code of HTML-structure of a page ([demo on Codepen here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zlntC)):

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  <section class="main-content" role="main">
    Main content: first in source order
  </section>

  <nav class="main-nav" role="navigation">
    Links
  </nav>

  <aside class="main-sidebar" role="complementary">
    Sidebar
  </aside>

</div>
```

To divide the `page-wrap` in 3 pieces with the `main-nav` twice as big as the sidebars, we could use flexbox. Another advantage is that the `main-content` element's position in the DOM is before the `main-nav` but with flexbox we could render it before the content. This is usefull for screenreaders so the content is read first.

We need to make the `page-wrap` a flexbox context. This way all the children become flexbox items:

```
.page-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 }
```

The order of the properties is important. Because some browsers support both implementations we need to specify the newest properties below the old properties. This is because the `display`-property isn't prefixed.

To add the widths of the items:

```
.main-content {
  width: 60%;
}
.main-nav,
.main-sidebar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  width: 20%;               /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
  -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

The last thing we need to do is change the ordering of the items, because now the `main-nav` is rendered after the `main-content`

```
.main-content {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -ms-flex-order: 2;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  -webkit-order: 2;               /* NEW - Chrome */
  order: 2;                       /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.main-nav {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;  
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;     
  -ms-flex-order: 1;     
  -webkit-order: 1;  
  order: 1;
}
.main-sidebar {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;  
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;     
  -ms-flex-order: 3;     
  -webkit-order: 3;  
  order: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [html5please.com](http://html5please.com/#flexbox), it sounds like the Flexbox spec is considered stable and there are tutorials at [Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/flexbox-basics/) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Note I'm not sure why html5please still recommends to avoid. Its text seems to suggest the opposite.