# How to make a matrix dynamically adjusting to parent width without (JS with example)

Tags: css, matrix

See this example ( http://jsfiddle.net/cpSbH/2/ ) and try to resize the window to see what I mean - it is adjusting margins to get as much items on one row as possible, but also to fully use the space and avoid gaps on one side (or both if it would be centred).

Is it possible to achieve this without a javascript?

Thanks

The code I wrote:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="item">item</div>
 ...
 <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var minMargin = 10;
  var width = $("#wrapper").innerWidth();
  var itemWidth = $('.item').outerWidth()+minMargin+minMargin

  var count = Math.floor(width/itemWidth)
  var space = width - (count*itemWidth);
  var margin = (space/(count));

  if(margin < minMargin) margin = minMargin;

  margin = Math.floor(margin/2);
  $('.item').css({'margin-left':margin,'margin-right':margin}); 
});
```

Comment: you need to make 1 media query for every number of posible columns, and then distribute them by percentages. for instance, calculate the min and maxwidth that allows for 3 columns, and set the width to 33%; calculate min and max width for 4, and set the width to 25%, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Although media queries aren't usable in my case (or it would be too complicated as the matrix wrapper size depends also on some more things than the window size), I can simulate the media query logic to measure width of the wrapper. 
So the modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpSbH/6/ (with some comments for anyone who would looks for the solution).

It is not ideal (still js), but much better than before.

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox model you can achieve the desired behavior with just CSS. The main problem will be browser compatibility.
Your CSS could look something like this:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around; /*or space-between*/
}
.item {
    flex: 1;
}
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796479/931340) you have some links to learn more about flex model.